# Android app respond to a particular linked clicked.

Tags: android, mobile, hyperlink

I want an an android app to respond to a particular link that is clicked from any other android app.
The problem is that i can't customize the app from which the linked is clicked.Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You cannot change the behaviour of clicking the link without the source for the other app.  It would be very insecure if you could!

Imagine being able to alter the behaviour of a link click in an app which is not yours.  I wouldn't be running Android if it allowed apps to do this!